# Pattern matching in OCaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I have an OCaml list of the type `(string*int) list`.
I have to traverse through the list and check for the `int` value. If for all the elements in my list, the property `int>=0` holds, then the list is "fine", else, if it fails at any one instance, then I have to return "fail".
For this, I made the following attempt

```
let rec check tlist = 
  match tlist with
    [] -> print_string "finished"
  | (s, i)::tail -> 
    if i < 0 then print_string "fail" 
    else check tail
```

on running this from the interpreter, I receive a warning that the pattern matching is not exhaustive.
Also, when I run it in the following input types

```
let z = [("ask", 1); ("tell", 2); ("three", 3); ("goal", -4)] ;;
```

it returns fail as expected but for

```
let z = [("ask", 1); ("tell", 2); ("three", 3); ("goal", 4)] ;; ,
```

it returns Exception:

```
Match_failure ("//toplevel//", 7, -22).
```

How to go about this?

Edit: Also, there is another part to the problem. I have to ensure that the string `s` is not repeated in the list. How to go about that?

Comment: Are u sure that it raises exception? For me it doesn't

Comment: Please update your question with transcript of an OCaml session triggering the exception.

Answer (score 3):

The code you post is fine, does not generate any warning, and work for the input you say.

If you want to improve it, you should try to separate the algorithm logic and input/output to have something more flexible: have your function return a boolean instead of `unit`.